# Dynamically adding Meta Boxes and Sorting them with Drag and Drop - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

**EDIT**

Developing a function in wordpress to display ranking such as the FIFA.com ranking @ [Fifa Ranking](http://www.fifa.com/fifa-world-ranking/ranking-table/men/index.html)

So far this is what i have achieved [LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz1n8.png)

I am able to generate these rows dynamically by clicking the 'Add More' button and I am also able to remove any particular row using jQuery.

This my jQuery for that

```
<script>
        var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = <?php echo $c - 1; ?>;
            $(".add").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;
                $('tbody').append('<tr class="sp-row sp-post alternate"><td><label for="sp_leagues_0_0"><span class="remove">Remove</span></label></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][rank]" value="" placeholder="-"></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][player]" value="" placeholder="-"></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][club]" value="" placeholder="-"></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][points]" value="" placeholder="-"></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][prev-points]" value="" placeholder="-"></td><td><input type="text" name="twbtdgs[' + count + '][position]" value="" placeholder="-"></td></tr>');
                return false;
            });
            $(".remove").live('click', function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I can successfully save this data in array and can fetch it back.

**PROBLEM**

I am not able to use the jQuery UI Sortable ( Which comes built in ), The main purpose to have this working will be to sort the rows and change the Rank number according to the new Sort order and this sort should be updated as soon as i update my post.

I can show the whole process of this for you guys to help me add this sortable jquery according to the need.

Comment: I updated my question now with the new progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final look of it

[image: New Progress]

Hooked a custom js file into the admin area

```
function my_enqueue($hook) 
{
    if ( 'post.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
        }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/admin/custom.js' ,array(), '4', true );
}
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Finally added this script into it

```
$('#ranking_info_id tbody').sortable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        handle: '.sort'
    });
```

The handle **'.sort'** was added at the end before the closing `</tr>` like `<td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>`

The way things get stored from the array including the new sort order is below :

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details($post_id){
global $post;

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post_id;
    if (isset($_POST['twbtdgs'])){
        $data = $_POST['twbtdgs'];
        update_post_meta($post_id,'twbtdgs',$data);
    }else{
        delete_post_meta($post_id,'twbtdgs');
    }
}
```